# Why codeigniter storing user ip address,user agent and users last activity data in cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

Why does Codeigniter do this? I mean isn't it very insecure if users can see which data is stored in their session? And and what if they change a value in the cookie? 
Can any one give me a suggestion please.

Answer (score 2):

Codeigniter provides also session data storing in database.
For using this method you need to go through few setps:

1. Setup a database connection
2. Create table where to store session data (table structure can be found in user guide)
3. Open config.php file and find $config['sess_use_database'] and change from FALSE to TRUE;

Additional information can be found at Codeigniters User Guide - [Session Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

They do this for flexibility for developers.  If you want the added security you can include the database session storage too, and encrypt it.  This means that the cookie has to match what is stored in the database, as well as the various encryption keys.

Even the standard PHP sessions use cookies, so CI actually offers more security due to the ability to easily encrypt & use a database.